# Does reservation based affirmative action really help in reducing inequality?

Tags: india, reference-request, inequality, affirmative-action

In India for example, caste and economic based affirmative action is used in political seats, education etc. My question is, have these methods of affirmative action in general (independent of India)  been shown to reduce inequality by statistical measures?

I mainly want to focus on AA by reservation of seats but would be interested in analysis of AA by other means.

Or do they have credibility by some other scientific metrics?

Comment: This question might benefit from focus. Even if we consider only a single country, the term “affirmative action” refers to a whole array of policies, practices, laws, and/or regulations. Some may help and others may not. Also, “inequality” could use some clarity and context. It could easily be shown that some private corporations have instituted voluntary policies that they called “affirmative action” that soon resulted in having more women and minorities on their boards of directors and in executive positions. So that’s a “yes” in that case. Asking about society as a whole is different.

Comment: I am talking about the popular conception of AA, giving a positive bias when considering applicants/ individuals by entites in power. In college admissions, for example, this manifests as weighting about 20% of the applicant in what ethinicity and sexuality the canditate is.

The basic question is regarding if to begin with, there is scientific reasons to think that affirmative action maybe a valid solution to inequality problems other than from intuition. Or, perhaps examples of societes which put faith in it, and actually elevated inequality using measurable things

Comment: But along @ToddWilcox's point, *whose* 'popular conception'? Where I've lived and discussed this topic at length, in the Southern/SE United States, there is a strong association of AA with quotas. But in the Western United States there is a strong association of AA with elimination of bias (reliance on pure objectivity). In the UK, such policies seem to be based on academic background in educational settings. In Austria, I'm not sure the concept even exists. You're going to have to be specificy what you mean by AA, and what statistical results you expect a study to produce (and in what areas).

Comment: Quotas can undeniably increase *representation*, as with the UK Labour Party's use of [all-woman shortlists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-women_shortlist) for parliamentary seats which increased the number of female MPs. Likewise, reserving spaces for minorities could hypothetically increase numbers. The effect on other measures of equality is likely to be slower and less clear-cut. So what measure of equality are you interested in, and what area of affirmative action are you interested in?

Comment: All which applies, or the strongest which is used in arguing for AA based on reservation @StuartF

Comment: The addition of "reservation based" to "affirmative action" in the title changes the meaning of this question quite a lot and seems like it would have justified the `India` tag.

Comment: If you see the question from the first iteration, it had in the subject that I am talking about reservation based AA @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica

Comment: Your title stayed at "Does affirmative action really help in reducing inequality?" until now.  I have done this myself, kinda changed the general question or rather clarified it by writing down more specifically what I had in mind.  That's something that can, on occasion, irritate people who have already contributed an answer.  Just a heads up, no more, no less.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "equality". In my mind, every kind of affirmative action is **inherently and obviously** opposed to equality - because equality **means** that everyone plays by the same rules, and that those rules are based only on what individuals did, and not on who they are or on actions that aren't personally their fault.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ideas floating around behind concepts like Affirmative Action and desegregation:

- **Exposure breeds tolerance**: people (as a rule) can be paranoid about people and things they are not familiar with. Forcing members of one group to be exposed to members of another group creates a level of familiarity and comfort that undercuts reactive oppressive attitudes
- **Exemplars**: getting a few people within an oppressed minority group into positions of power and authority serves as an example to other members of the group that it is possible to rise within society, which encourages higher goals and greater effort across the minority group
- Fiscal ambiguity: in segregated societies, funds for education and public services are invariably allocated disproportionately towards the hegemonic group. Programs like AA make it more difficult to funnel public funds to the benefit of one group over another, because it becomes more difficult to tell which locations are exclusive to one group or the other
- Mentorship and leadership: getting a few people within an oppressed minority group into positions of power and authority means that money, effort, and power tend to flow into the minority community, not away from it. That creates opportunities, raises property values, increases community prestige, and offers other benefits

None of these intuitions plays out quite as expected in the real world — I mean, what does? — but the general principle of reducing alienation and isolation clearly has a slow, cumulative effect on a society. Consider, for instance, that in 1960 there were 19 women and 4 blacks in Congress, and as of today there are 144 women and 65 blacks. While Affirmative Action didn't cause that change directly, it created the attitudes that allowed it.

Comment: Counterexample: the proportion of women in Swiss parliament rose from 5% to 39% in the last 50 years - without any affirmative action taken by the government. I am therefore not convinced that the correlation you describe is a causation as you claim.

Comment: Also, there is at least one way in which affirmative action may be harmful: If affirmative action promotes people by minority status rather than competency, incompetent minority members may be promoted, and thus reinforce the stereotype that members of this minority are incapable of doing the job well.

Comment: @meriton Just because something gets better without it doesn't mean it doesn't help. I would also suggest that there is still room for improvement in the swiss parliament as the balance of men and women could get closer to match the general population.

Comment: I would never dare imagine a real world political system to be perfect :-) Still, I find it instructive that the Swiss have achieved a better representation for women in their parliament (39%) than the US (29%). If Affirmative Action is necessary for society to change, how did the Swiss change more without it? At the very least, this hints at the existence of other factors, and that Affirmative Action may not be as crucial as some people make it out to be.

Comment: Note on terminology: At least in the US, “Black people” is strongly preferred over “blacks”.

Comment: That Swiss example shows the problem with this Q -- we've got 3 countries so far, and sex and race. It's too broad.

Comment: @meriton There's no logical principle allowing you to disprove/rebut "A implies/causes B" by showing "not A and B", as you've tried to do. "This is wet, but there was no rain" doesn't rebut "rain causes wetness". You'd need to show "A and not B", but one counter-example still doesn't disprove that something is a contributing factor to something else, because there are often many other factors involved. But then you seem to have misread both the question and answer, because the question is "does AA really help", yet you said "if AA is necessary...", which are two fundamentally different things.

Comment: The high representation of woman in the Swiss parliament is apparently to a large part due to campaigning by groups like Alliance F, who are in favour of affirmative action by enshrining proportional representation of woman in the Swiss constitution. So using Swiss as a counterexample is a bit like arguing that the US did not need desegregation, because Rosa Parks was already sitting in the front of the bus. Also the Gleichstellungsgesetz of 1996 makes it e.g. illegal to pay women less for equal work, which might also be considered affirmative action.

Comment: @meriton: The question was whether AA *helped*, not whether it was *necessary* or *sufficient* to the task. Bless the Swiss (one of the most racially homogenous peoples in the world) for being open-minded about women (though interestingly, women didn't even get the right to vote there until the 1970s). But I don't see how that speaks to the point here.

Comment: @meriton Is anyone actually saying Affirmative Action is necessary to reduce inequality or that there aren't any factors involved? I haven't seen anyone say this, so I'm not convinced the hypothetical people you're arguing against even exist. What people might say is that AA is the best way to reduce inequality that they know of. If you can show that it isn't a good way or if you can prove that you have a better way, I'm sure many would like to hear it.

Comment: @meriton: Also, let's drop the coded racist tripe. The idea that AA entrenches 'incompetent' minorities in positions of power rests on the idea that minorities are intrinsically incompetent (i.e., that in a 'fair' system minorities would never succeed to power; they'd always lose to 'better' whites). But AA was meant to give competent, intelligent, effective members of minorities a chance to compete on a level playing field and succeed on their merits.

Comment: @meriton: Hell, I could easily make the argument (as many, many others have) that the current system of white privilege does nothing except entrench incompetent whites in positions of power. I mean, how else do we explain that George W Bush (who failed at every business he tried to run) or Donald Trump (a pathological liar and grifter who only makes money by cheating others) became president? How else do we explain Matt Gaetz, Jim Jordan, or Marjorie Taylor Greene? Are stupid, incompetent white people *still* better than the brightest and best of minorities?

Comment: I know. My comment aims at the last sentence of your answer, which says "Affirmative Action created the attitudes that allowed change". This makes it sound like these attitudes, which "allow", i.e. are necessary for, change, would not otherwise have emerged. If this was not your meaning, perhaps a clearer phrasing would help? And if it is your meaning, perhaps you could evidence to support your claim? Because I don't know to what extent affirmative action caused these changes, and I think that would be germane to the question.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: Yes, they are in favor of implementing affirmative action, but have not succeeded at turning this into law. And still society changed, and elected more and more women into parliament. As for the Gleichstellungsgesetz: yes, discrimination is forbidden by law. But does outlawing discrimination count as "affirmative action"? According to Google affirmative action is "the practice or policy of favouring individuals belonging to groups known to have been discriminated against previously; positive discrimination". Nobody is being favored by outlawing discrimination?

Comment: @TedWrigley; 'the current system of white privilege...' is there really a system of white privilege? I don't agree. And no one said that stupid white people are better than everyone else

Comment: @TedWrigley There are also a whole lot of competent white people, so reducing the problem of incompetent politicians down to "white privilege" seems quite flawed. "Stupid, incompetent white people" are "better" than smart, competent white people as well. That's because politics is little more than a popularity contest: politicians are successful when they can convince the right people (including the general public) to support them (and/or they have enough money to fund their own campaign). Race might be one factor, but there are many other reasons someone incompetent might be popular.

Comment: besides, the point @meriton was trying to make is whether AA is as crucial and as beneficial as some might think. Has anyone actually proved that it is?

Comment: @TedWrigley; Exposure can and does happen without AA, Competent members of minority groups can and do succeed without AA, your point on fiscal ambiguity is flawed, since it assumes that we live in a segregated society (which we don't). I do agree with your point on membership and leadership (I can clearly see the benefit of that, being a member of a minority group myself), but again, who said they need the help of AA in getting positions of leadership?

Comment: @meriton: Perhaps it is an overstatement; I think I meant to imply something more nuanced.  let me consider it for a day and see if I can phrase a revision.

Comment: @user27954: Speaking as a member of the ostensibly privileged class... Yeah, there is definitely a system of white privilege, and it's such a glaringly obvious set of privileges that I can only attribute denying it to willful ignorance or extreme naïveté. I'm not actually interested in whether you (or anyone else) believes it or not, just as I'm not interested in whether you (or anyone else) believes that the world is a sphere. The evidence naturally points one way, and the cognitive contortions needed to make it point somewhere else are only worth chuckle-time.

Comment: @user27954: I'm not about to claim that AA is perfect, and I happen to believe that AA has a half-life of usefulness, and will eventually have to be discarded as policy. But AA is an important step in leveling the playing field between minorities and whites. It's true that incompetent people sometimes succeed where they shouldn't for whatever reason, and that superior people sometimes fail for reasons beyond their control. But in both cases those 'reasons' should not be tied (directly or indirectly) to race.

Comment: @user27954: When we get to the point in this country where a minority individual can float his way into the US Presidency (or CEO of a company, or what you will) the same way W Bush did — prat-falling upwards like a real-world Forrest Gump — then I'll think we've achieved what AA tried to achieve. It will still be a d*mned stupid world, mind you, but at least it will be a fair one.

Comment: @meriton perhaps with affirmative action women would no longer be underrepresented in the Swiss parliament.  The decrease in the degree to which they are underrepresented is no doubt attributable to the fact that they are now allowed to vote, which has only been the case for ... 50 years.  How many experienced female politicians were there in 1971 who could mount a credible candidacy?

Comment: @TedWrigley; I wouldn't trash a belief without reading up on it. But I find that in the answer and comments you post, white privilege and others of the sort are absolute truths, and anyone who disagrees is naive. I wouldn't mind it so much if you'd bring proof to support your claims, but you don't. You don't even explain the logic behind your position...

Comment: These beliefs are stated as fact, and that's what I don't agree with. If you'd include something more substantial to support your claims than just 'there is definitely a system of white privilege', I might have an easier time understanding your position. And if you believe that my reasoning is incorrect, I'd appreciate an explanation as to why you think so. In addition, I find it quite interesting that you call 'white privilege' fact and anything else is labeled a belief. Maybe it is worth considering that some people think 'white privilege' is a belief, not a fact. @TedWrigley

Comment: Again, if 'the evidence naturally points one way' as you claim, it would only help your case to include them @TedWrigley

Comment: @phoog; you have a point, but I was just wondering whether women are really underrepresented. I think it's necessary to see how many women want to be part of the Swiss parliament as opposed to men. Maybe more men choose it as a career. For example, if 60% of the candidates are men and 40% are women (because they chose this as a career), I'd say the number of women in parliament would reflect that. I'm not familiar with the system, so this is all just speculation, but it may be worth looking into

Comment: @TedWrigley There is an important distinction in the two types of Exemplars that exist. One promotes racism and the other doesn't. Any Exemplar that was promoted and propped up without having the necessary skills to be in that position and clearly underperforms amongst peers will increase racism. meriton is talking about this subset, which is very different from assuming all AA people underperform or lack the skills. In one, the Exemplar takes the path cleared for them. The other the Exemplar is carried through the path. The latter receives the negative reaction. Pointing it out isn't racism.

Comment: "Consider, for instance, that in 1960 there were 19 women and 4 blacks in Congress, and as of today there are 144 women and 65 blacks." - **okay, and**? If my aunt's knitting circle has ten women and no men in it, is that "inequality"? Does it make the members "sexist"? "But in both cases those 'reasons' should not be tied (directly or indirectly) to race." Cool. Affirmative action is, definitionally, the **explicit** tying of those reasons to race, resulting from someone not liking the value of a particular statistic.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Hmmm...  Is your aunt's knitting circle explicitly excluding men, and then making rules about what men can do *outside* the knitting circle? Do they run around town poking men with knitting needles when men refuse to comply with the rules? I mean, if they did they'd be pretty terrifying I think, and I suspect you might have a few unpleasant words to say about the situation (at least until auntie's crew knit your mouth shut). The public and private sectors are **very** different things; don't use disingenuous examples, please.

Comment: No, I think my analogy fits perfectly, because I am not sexist, and therefore I don't believe that men or women will inherently pass different kinds of laws. Also because I understand that lobbyists hold more power than congress critters in the US anyway.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel:I have no idea whether you're sexist or not, and don't really care (that's your business unless you somehow make it mine). However, I can't abide pollyanna-ism. It is an easily verifiable fact, across many cultures and centuries, that male-dominated political systems have crafted laws that disadvantaged and oppressed women. It's not gender so much as self-interest. If men are in power it's in their interest to undercut women's rights; if women were in power it would be in their interest to undercut men's rights.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Defending the rights of the powerless requires a sense of integrity — or at least of *noblesse oblige* — that is sadly lacking in most of the human species. The only proper solution is full and equal representation, so that no side has the opportunity or collective power to implement into their baser urges.