# Why should one wish to increase representation of under-represented group?

Tags: inequality, affirmative-action

Perhaps an obvious question, but I can't give a precise answer. Exactly, why the idea of AA to increase the representation of minority group through methods is gaining prominence in recent times[(*)](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/asian-america/cal-state-schools-add-caste-anti-discrimination-policy-rcna12602)? I mean, what reasons should motivate a society to increase representation of minority groups through methods like affirmative action?

---

**Some thoughts I've had:**

I thought about the "fairness" argument, but if we really get to the meat of it, we are all fundamentally different. The manifestation of race based differences are due to the different genes in people and the environment they grew up in. Taking the idea of affirmative action to the logical extreme, wouldn't society in the future have AA based on literally what genes a person has? This seems a bit absurd to me.

On this track, would we be compromising the quality of the candidates in the upper position as in attempts to give equivalent gene reservation, wouldn't we push those with worser genes  ( chance for disease, lower cognitive ability) into upper position.

Eg: Let's say for example, would we also give people with some rare disease genes reservation benefits/ AA benefits so that they can also be represented in the system.

**Note: I do 'feel' AA as a whole is a good thing, the issue is when we try to properly try to define concepts relating to it, and the edges of it's meaning.**

---

Related:

[Does Affirmative action really help in reducing inequality?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70319/does-reservation-based-affirmative-action-really-help-in-reducing-inequality)

The following is linked since usually these underrepresented groups own lesser amount of wealth in the country:

[Correlation between wealth and Academic performance?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/181309/is-there-any-research-showing-a-correlation-between-wealth-and-academic-performa)

Comment: As you know, Politics Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a debate forum. This question reads more like a prompt to start a debate rather than a question one can give a straight "correct" answer to. And the fact that the sections "Some thoughs I've had" is much longer than the actual question makes it seem like the questions primary purpose is to give the author a vessel to share their personal thoughts with an audience, rather than to receive information.

Comment: I do understand this is a touchy issue for many, but the idea of starting of a debate was not my intention. I wrote the section of my thoughts, because I've asked these question to other people and these were answers I received and rebuttals I came up with. 

The nature of the question/answer being felt as sharing of one's thought is inevitable on this site. As it's people who are writing question and answers and whatever is written by people inherit the biases of people. @Philipp

Comment: meta: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6128/question-labelled-bad-faith-post-without-much-reasoning

Comment: People of the lowest caste of India are there because they do not receive the same quality of life and education as higher castes, because they are lowest caste, because they...

Comment: Technically speaking caste is based on Birth at the moment, not on economic status. However, yes, it is related to social capital as UCS own about more than 50% of wealth when they make up less than 35% of population. There was another question I asked which gave evidence for the fact that money determines education run, but, my question is this particular point completely ruled out? Is there anyway to know it's not true? @CGCampbell

Comment: @Buraian I really do understand the caste system. If the Dalit were afforded the same opportunities as the other castes, and not simply ignored, then some of them would surely have the mind-set (via education) and where-withal (via quality of life) to fight for an end to the despicable segregation. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: "I wrote the section of my thoughts," You can also just self-answer questions here. For example keep the question short and neutral and then in an answer say all what you wanted to say about the topic.

Comment: My experience with self answering on some certain other sites was quite bad, so I stopped doing that (eg: MSE). Also, it would be that if I had self answer, it wouldn't really be an answer but a scramble of thoughts..

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be under the assumption that minorities currently are not represented because they are inferior. When in fact it's because of discrimination (just looking at the supreme court, it's rather unreasonable to assume that white, Christian, non-Catholic men are vastly superior to women, non-white people, non-Christians, and Catholics, or indeed any other religions).

Combating this discrimination results in a larger pool of talented people to choose from, and thus increases quality.

Additionally, a diversity in representation will lead to a diversity in points of views, which will result in better outcomes as more views are considered.

For a corporate view on the issue, see eg [here](https://www.affirmativeactionconsulting.com/benefits-of-affirmative-action/).

And of course, the fairness argument is rather valid.

Comment: What sense do you think I consider them inferior in? Suppose one takes everything you said as a given, it still doesn't explain the premise I put forward of people being fundamentally different and genes

Comment: @Buraian "The manifestation of race based differences..." This in the original question. Fundamentally there are no significant differences between people based on their race. Certainly not to the extent that as a group they would choose or be less suited to any particular job.

Comment: @Buraian In the sense that based on "fundamentally different" "genes", they are not capable of holding "higher position", or are of inferior "quality" as "candidates in the upper position" and of "lower cognitive ability".

Comment: It is well understood to me that these different traits in itself are most likely inherited independently. I could understand how one could come to interpret what I said in that way, but , really that is not what I meant. @tim

Comment: @Jontia Would you say the NBA is engaging in pro-black discrimination, given its disproportionate percentage of black players?

Comment: @user76284 I think you'd have to look at wider issues. Reaching a professional sports team is the end result of a long path, the US in particular charts this path through high school and college teams, rather than personal hobbies as is the case in the UK. Society shows that as a path to success where black children see black role models regularly. It's also a path that the schools and colleges encourage via scholarships where the playing field is levelled by the common path through school teams, rather than at home assistance or tutoring.

Comment: @Jontia You claimed that "*Fundamentally there are no significant differences between people based on their race. Certainly not to the extent that as a group they would choose or be less suited to any particular job.*" Why are you contradicting yourself? Does the NBA engage in pro-black discrimination or not? Does society engage in pro-black discrimination for NBA players or not?

Comment: There are significantly better ways to have diversity of opinion like having people from different professions, political parties, or other things that matter more than race.

Comment: Also, you're ignoring that women go into different fields besides politics because of their own interests rather than solely discrimination.